# How do I make it obvious that a question must be selected in order to filter a components list

Tags: usability, gui-design, layout, user-expectation

[image]

This is a data analysis tool. The user poses a question, and then adds data analysis snippets that helps answer that question.

On the left of the page, there is the list of questions and a field for entering additional questions. On the right is the list of components that are linked to the selected question.

Is there a way to show that they are viewing a list of questions, and that they must select one from the list in order to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here would be to go for [progressive disclosure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_disclosure) where you first show the list of questions and then tell the user that he needs to select a question. once a question is selected, then you can show the related content.

Here is a quick wireframe to illustrate the flow

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnMmWU.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>